# Laravel 5.8: Eloquent where clauses returns null but does not execute if..empty condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a Controller method like this:

```
public function postNewWallet(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $find = UserWallet::where('user_id',$user)->where('wallet_id', $request->wallet_choose)->get();
        // dd($find);
        if(empty($find)){
            UserWallet::create([
                'user_id' => $user,
                'wallet_id' => $request->wallet_choose,
                'balance' => 0
            ]);

            flash()->overlay('Submitted', 'Information submitted', 'success');
        }else{
            flash()->overlay('Warning!', 'User has the defined wallet', 'warning');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

So I have added two `where` clauses to check if any data exists with the `user_id` of `$user` AND `wallet_id` of `$request->wallet_choose`.

Then if `$find` returns empty,  add a new record. Otherwise shows an alert `warning` message.

Now I test this for a user who does not have any record on `user_wallet` table but it returns the Warning message `User has the defined wallet` somehow.

However if I uncomment `dd($find)`, I get this as result:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2551 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

So it seems to be empty. But why does not add new record to the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty($collection)` will always return `false`. If you want to know if a Collection is empty you call `isEmpty()` on it, `$collection->isEmpty()`. You could also call `first()` instead of `get()` on the Query Builder to attempt to retrieve the first record instead of all records; `first()` returns the Model instance or `null`, which would work with your `empty($result)` check.

In your code here you are never actually using anything from this Collection though as you are just doing a check to see if records exist it seems. You should use the `exists` method on the Query Builder to do a query that checks for existence so you don't have to return records that you are never using.

```
$exists = UserWallet::where('user_id', $user)
    ->where('wallet_id', $request->wallet_choose)
    ->exists(); 
// $exists is a bool
```

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-isempty) `isEmpty`

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Query Builder - Aggregates - Determining If Records Exist](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates) `exists`